# Can baseline grid be linked to a body copy paragraph style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, grids, paragraph-styles

I am working with some type thats aligned to the baseline grid. I have made the baseline grid the same as the type leading. I have been changing and playing around with the bodycopy pt size but whenever I change the baseline grid is there a way to update it automatically everytime I change the pt size? As I have been going back into preferences constantly to change it everytime I update the pt size and its a bit tedious. Or if there is any other more efficient method to use alternatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, no automatic updating on the baseline grid.

Ideally, you would design a few pages and manually adjust until it looks right, gets approved, etc ... **before** adding so much content that it becomes tedious.

Comment: Thank you I think in terms of work flow I will leave the baseline grid towards the end of the process

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.

The baseline grid is not *meant* to move once it's set. That's kind of the point of using the grid.